# what camera should I buy as a beginner?

Tags: film, camera-settings, photography-basics

I really love to take pictures from all kinds of cameras that I have exprienced with,I want to finally buy my first camera but i dont know which one is the best for me,any advice?

Comment: Really hard to answer without more information about what kind of shooting you have in mind - the "best camera" for landscape, portrait, street or underwater photography, to pick just a few types, would be rather different... :)

Comment: @PhilipKendall OP did not explicitly ask about digital cameras. In fact, he/she tagged it "film".

Comment: @bvy It's also tagged as "camera-settings" which doesn't seem to be relevant, so I'm not convinced of the accuracy of the tags. Honalolo, could you please clarify if you're interested in digital or film cameras?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question "film" I assume you are considering a film camera. If this is correct, and it is a strong assumption, I recommend a simple manual camera with fixed prime lens of the normal focal length.

[Yashica 124G](http://istillshootfilm.org/post/66810081483/yashica-mat-124g-medium-format-tlr-camera-review) is a nice medium format TLR. It is rugged, it has integrated exposure meter (might be even working), there are still people around who remember how to repair a broken one and it does not cost a fortune - so if you decide it was a huge mistake (or that you wish to to graduate to a more sophisticated one) it will not hurt you badly.

If you think small format better fits your needs consider a late 1970's design, such as the [Pentax K1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentax_K1000), East German Praktica (any model from the L line) or [Canon AE-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_AE-1). This was an era when mechanical cameras were developed close to perfection, but  before electronics took over. Mechanical cameras seem to have aged better than electronic gadgets from 1980s and 1990s - when these break they stay broken.

Neither of the cameras have the kind of features that serve only distract, such as a ton of zoom lenses, creative modes and awkward settings accessible only via menu items.

Comment: At roughly $5 (USD) a roll for 12 shots, medium format film is not that cheap. 35mm is a probably a better introduction to film shooting. The 124G is a great camera though -- rugged and with sharp glass.

Comment: No film can be as cheap as space on SD card of your mobile. IMHO this is not a bad thing, as the awarness of cost focuses your mind. Is the image worth pressing the shutter? Can it be improved in some way? If yes, then do it before hitting the "commit" button. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: I don't disagree! I just don't think MF is the place for a newcomer to start. 35mm film is cheaper, processing is usually cheaper and more likely to be found locally, and 35mm cameras are cheaper and much more abundant. Even if cost is no issue, at two to three frames for every one (of MF), 35mm allows a new shooter to experiment and learn more readily. If your assumption is correct (it's the same as mine) that the OP is interested in film cameras, then there's no point comparing any film to the cost of a memory card.

Comment: @bvy you might be right. I shoot, and love, the medium format; this might have clouded my judgement. I have edited my answer to list some simple and reliable 35mm cameras - and let the OP make his informed decision.

Comment: K-1000 with kit 50mm is a great choice. They can be easily found and won't break the bank.

Comment: As one who first learned photography in the era when everything was manual focus and film, I disagree. In the age of digital I think there are way too many advantages that allow one to learn at a much faster pace (that is also cheaper in the long run) using digital, even if the ultimate goal is to become a film specialist. Us old-timers may like to brag about having to learn to be a "real" photographer but the fact of the matter is we didn't have a choice. I strongly maintain that I could have developed much easier and faster had digital been around back then. Once the lessons are learned...

Comment: ... regarding the basics of exposure, composition, and even image development (the digital darkroom is a remarkable teaching tool that teaches many of the concepts, if not the specific techniques, of the wet darkroom) then they can be applied to film.

Comment: @MichaelClark I neither agree nor disagree with you; using film or digital is for a hobby photographer a personal choice (it has consequences, but deep down it is about you). But since the OP seemed to indicate interest in a film camera by tagging the question "film" I recommended some film ones that are widely considered beginner friendly.